# i am getting an error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- productResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am getting an error in the chrome console :

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <-
>   $resource <- p roductResource ,

I already check the angular resource bet it seems ok .

```
var app = angular.module('productManagement', ['common.service']);




angular
    .module("common.services",
        ["ngResource"])
    .constant("appSettings",
        {
            serverPath: "http://localhost:49896/"
        });


angular.module("common.service", []).
    factory("productResource", ["$resource",
        "appSettings",
        productResource]);


function productResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:sku");


angular
    .module("productManagement")
    .controller("productListCtrl",
        productListCtrl);

function productListCtrl(productResource) {
    var vm = this;

    productResource.query(function (data) {
        vm.products = data;
    });
```

Comment: Having modules with names `common.services` and `common.service` is confusing and error prone. The `ngResource` is a dependency of the `common.services` module. The `$resource` service is being called in the `common.service` module.

Answer (score 0):

Your module reference is in the `app` variable

`var app = angular.module('productManagement', ['common.service']);`

You should do it like this

```
app.module("productManagement")
    .controller("productListCtrl",
        productListCtrl);

function productListCtrl(productResource) {
    var vm = this;

    productResource.query(function (data) {
        vm.products = data;
    });
```